# Latitude represented as a Matrix

Tags: latitude-longitude, netcdf, gis-principle

I have some NetCDF data where I have a few variables

```
lat : dimensions - (x,y)
lon : dimensions - (x,y)
x : dimensions - (x,)
y : dimensions - (y,)
temp : dimensions - (year, y, x)
```

I am struggling a bit to understand what a two dimensional latitude or longitude represent. To my knowledge latitude should be a 1 dimensional vector and not a 2D matrix, and the same for longitude.

From what I think, for a particular latitude value (i.e 51.34) should fall between some x and y coordinate range (y1,y2,x1,x2) in the lat variable and similarly in the lon variable (y3,y4,x3,x4) and that should represent the x and y range (perhaps something like bounding box) in the temperature variable.

What does this type of (x,y) for format for latitude represent?

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63169963/why-latitudes-and-longitudes-are-two-dimensional-arrays-in-netcdf-file), the two dimensional representation is seen for projected coordinates. The projected coordinates are used to refer to the cartesian coordinates.

For instance, a cartesian system has a point *(x, y)*. If it is projected, it will have a different location in the projected grid, since the origin and axis will change after projection. To refer the projected location of the point, we will need the grid location of *x*, which can be represented as *(x', y')*. The changed *x* will have a new coordinate comprising the *x'* and *y'* of the new projected system.

[image]